Why do XeLaTeX and ucharclasses falsely claim my characters are in italics?
I am using ucharclasses to automatically switch fonts for Latin (using Noto Serif) and for Anatolian Hieroglyphs (using Noto Sans Anatolian Hieroglyphs).  The Anatolian Hieroglyphs font is available only in a regular, upright style; there are no italics.  When I write Anatolian Hieroglyphs on the same line as Latin characters inside an \emph{} command, XeLaTeX sometimes complains that I am trying to set the Anatolian Hieroglyphs in italics.
Here is a minimum example demonstrating the problem:
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}

\usepackage[Latin,Anatolian Hieroglyphs]{ucharclasses}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\defaultfont}{Noto Serif}
\newfontfamily{\anatolianfont}[Path=./fonts/, Extension=.otf]{NotoSansAnatolianHieroglyphs-Regular}
\setTransitionsForLatin{\defaultfont}{}
\setTransitionTo{AnatolianHieroglyphs}{\anatolianfont}

\begin{document}
waniza =  % This works fine

\emph{waniza} =  % But this produces a warning
\end{document}

And here is the warning emitted by XeLaTeX:
(/opt/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/NotoSansAnatolianHieroglyphs-Regular(0)/m/it
' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/NotoSansAnatolianHieroglyphs-Regular(0)/m/n' inst
ead on input line 13.

[1] (./test.aux)

LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.

 )

Why does XeLaTeX emit this warning when it's only the Latin characters that are in the \emph{} command?  How can I work around this to eliminate the warning?

I guess you want \newfontface instead  of \newfontfamily

I don't have the font but after waniza =   you are setting Hieroglyphs. That will automatically change back when you hit a latin character but you switch to italic before that.

You should use \newfontface to begin with.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[Latin,Anatolian Hieroglyphs]{ucharclasses}

\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\newfontface{\anatolianfont}{NotoSansAnatolianHieroglyphs-Regular}[
  Path=./,
  Extension=.ttf
]
\setTransitionsFor{AnatolianHieroglyphs}{\bgroup\normalfont\anatolianfont}{\egroup}

\begin{document}

waniza =   And some text follows

\emph{waniza} =   And some text follows

\end{document}


However, I believe it's better to mark up the usages of those characters.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\newfontface{\anatolianfont}{NotoSansAnatolianHieroglyphs-Regular}[
  Path=./,
  Extension=.ttf
]
\NewDocumentCommand{\AHier}{m}{{%
  \normalfont\anatolianfont #1%
}}

\begin{document}

waniza = \AHier{ } And some text follows

\emph{waniza} = \AHier{ } And some text follows

\end{document}


I have the ttf rather than otf but after waniza =   you are setting Hieroglyphs. That will automatically change back when you hit a latin character but you switch to italic before that.
So for example you get no warning from
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}

\usepackage[Latin,Anatolian Hieroglyphs]{ucharclasses}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\defaultfont}{Noto Serif}
\newfontfamily{\anatolianfont}[Extension=.ttf]{NotoSansAnatolianHieroglyphs-Regular}
\setTransitionsForLatin{\defaultfont}{}
\setTransitionTo{AnatolianHieroglyphs}{\anatolianfont}

\begin{document}
waniza =  % This works fine

a\emph{waniza} =  % But this produces a warning
\end{document}

as the font switches back on the a.
As you don't really want an a there you need to make sure the font switches back before that eg by using a group, you get no warning from
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}

\usepackage[Latin,Anatolian Hieroglyphs]{ucharclasses}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\defaultfont}{Noto Serif}
\newfontfamily{\anatolianfont}[Extension=.ttf]{NotoSansAnatolianHieroglyphs-Regular}
\setTransitionsForLatin{\defaultfont}{}
\setTransitionTo{AnatolianHieroglyphs}{\anatolianfont}

\begin{document}
waniza = {} % This works fine

\emph{waniza} = {} % But this produces a warning
\end{document}

